# Jumping from one dimension (1D) to two dimensions (2D) Part II

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

Here is a sample data file

```
data = {{-10,3,1},{-7.5,12,3},{-1.5,5,2},{2,4,4},{3,7,4},{6,9,5},{7,1,5},
 {8,3,1},{9,12,2},{10,8,5}};
```

The first element of the list is a point on the x-axis, while the other two are integers for other information.

A color code regarding the second integer of the list

```
valrange = {0, 43};
data[[All, 2]] = Rescale[data[[All, 2]], valrange];
colfunc[x_, cf_] := If[(x[[3]] == 0), White, ColorData[cf][1 - x[[2]]]];

S0 = Graphics[{{PointSize[0.005]}, Point[{#[[1]], 0}, VertexColors -> 
     colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@data}]
```

[image]

I would like the following: Get some height. In particular, for every color point $x_0$ to create a vertical line at $x_0$ with the same color let's say from $y_{min} = −1$ up to $y_{max} = 1$.

I tried

```
S0 = Graphics[{{Thickness[0.001]}, Line[{{#[[1]], -1}, {#[[1]], 1}}, 
     VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@ data}]
```

but it does not work. All lines have black color.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}, VertexColors -> Red]}]`

Comment: So provide at least two elements or don't use VertexColors but just put the color before line. p.s. when you have {Pointsize[_]} hidden inside a list, it won't affect anything.

Comment: @Kuba I don't quite understand your suggestion. I want shades of blue not specific colors.

Comment: @Kuba Whan I evaluate `Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}, VertexColors -> Red]}]` the line is black.

Comment: Yes, the point of that code was - you are doing the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], 
   Line[{{#[[1]], -1}, {#[[1]], 1}}, 
      VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@ data}] /. 
        Rule[VertexColors, c_] :> VertexColors -> {c, c}
```

[image]

Or, shorter

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.01], Line[{{#[[1]], -1}, {#[[1]], 1}},
   VertexColors -> {#, #} &[colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]]] & /@ data}]
```

Comment: It works like a charm! A quick question: why `S0 = Graphics[{Thickness[0.001], Line[{{#[[1]], -1}, {#[[1]], 1}}, 
     VertexColors -> colfunc[#, "DeepSeaColors"]] & /@ data}]` does not work and we need an extra rule?

Comment: By definition `VertexColors ` needs two color directives. `VertexColors -> {Red, Blue}` would blend  between `Red` and `Blue`. So, if we want only one color we have to write `VertexColors -> {Red, Red}`